# only validate specific password field with jQuery validate password

Tags: jquery, passwords, jquery-validate

Trying to do a password change page with `password`, `new_password` and `confirm_password`.

I have two problems:

1. The password validator strength fiield is being triggered by input to all three password fields whereas I only want it to apply to the `new_password` field where the user chooses their new password.
2. The validation isn't appending the text error messages, it changes the class to be checked or unchecked fine so a cross or tick is displayed but doesn't give the user a message saying why a field has failed validation.

I'm using jQuery 1.8.3, `jquery.validate` and `jquery.validate.password` from bassistance.

Any ideas gratefully received.

HTML and jQuery below:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" method="POST" action="/frontend_dev.php/profile/change-password" name="change_account_data_form" id="change_account_password_form">

                    <table cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                                                </td>
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label for="current_password">Current password:</label></td>
                        <td><input style="display: none;" name="change_password[password]" id="password" class="text" type="password"><input class="text" type="text"></td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label for="password">New password:</label></td>
                        <td><input style="display: none;" name="change_password[new_password]" id="new_password" class="text password" type="password"><input class="text password" type="text"></td>
                        <td><div class="password-meter">
                                                            <div class="password-meter-message"> </div>
                                                            <div class="password-meter-bg">
                                                                    <div class="password-meter-bar"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><label for="password_confirm">Confirm password:</label></td>
                        <td><input style="display: none;" name="change_password[password_confirm]" id="password_confirm" class="text" type="password"><input class="text" type="text"></td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                    </tbody></table>
        <input name="change_password[id]" value="2" id="change_password_id" type="hidden"><input name="change_password[_csrf_token]" value="66dbd4dc532ad1c9dd668e5e86235136" id="change_password__csrf_token" type="hidden">                       
                <div class="submitBlock">
            <input class="buttonSubmit" value="" type="submit">
                </div>

        </form>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
var validator = $("#change_account_password_form").validate({
        debug:true,
        errorClass: 'jqueryError',
    rules: {

        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
        },
        new_password: {
            password: "#new_password",
                            minlength: 8
        },
        password_confirm: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: "#new_password"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        password: {
            required: "Enter your current password",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        },
        new_password: {
            required: "Enter your new password",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters")
        },
        password_confirm: {
            required: "Repeat your password",
            minlength: jQuery.format("Enter at least {0} characters"),
            equalTo: "Enter the same password as above"
        }
    },
    // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.prependTo( element.parent().next() );
    },
    // specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    },
    // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
    success: function(label) {
        // set &nbsp; as text for IE
        label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("jqueryChecked");
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a list of issues...

1)  You must target the `input` fields by `name` and not `id`.  Since your `input` `name` contains brackets, you must surround with quotes.

```
"change_password[password]": {
     required: true,
     minlength: 8
},
```

2)  Your target fields all have `style="display: none;"`, so they would never be seen, contain data, or be validated.  And you also have another `input` right next to it without any `name` where the data is actually entered.  This setup will never work and I have no idea why you've done this.

```
<input style="display: none;" name="change_password[password]" id="password" class="text" type="password">
<input class="text" type="text">
```

3)  You have a `rule` called `password` on the second `input` field, yet its corresponding `message` is for the `required` `rule`.  <s>(Simply keep `class="password"` on the second `input` field if you want to use `jquery.validate.password`...</s>  **See edit below.<sup>1</sup>**

```
<input class="text password" name="change_password[new_password]" id="new_password" type="password">
```

Demo does not contain `jquery.validate.password` simply because there is no CDN for it.  However, it's [usage is straightforward as per this link](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-password-validation/).)  **See edit below.<sup>1</sup>**

4) On the third `input` field, you have two rules and three messages... `minlength` message is superfluous since you only need to match second `input` field.

5)  You don't need `jQuery.format()` around the `minlength` messages... they'll work fine by themselves.

6)  You forgot to pass `form` into the `submitHandler:` function, like this: `submitHandler: function(form) {`

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/kJxZB/**

**Working Demo #2 (see answer edit below):  http://jsfiddle.net/4JEUx/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#change_account_password_form").validate({
        errorClass: 'jqueryError',
        rules: {
            "change_password[password]": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            "change_password[new_password]": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            "change_password[password_confirm]": {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#new_password"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "change_password[password]": {
                required: "Enter your current password",
                minlength: "Enter at least {0} characters"
            },
            "change_password[new_password]": {
                required: "Enter your new password",
                minlength: "Enter at least {0} characters"
            },
            "change_password[password_confirm]": {
                required: "Repeat your password",
                equalTo: "Enter the same password as above"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.prependTo(element.parent().next());
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert("submitted!"); // for demo
            return false;  // for demo
        },
        success: function (label) {
            // set &nbsp; as text for IE
            label.html("&nbsp;").addClass("jqueryChecked");
        }
    });
});
```

**Documentation:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation**

---

**<sup>1</sup>EDIT:**

This is the same Demo as above, except that the `jquery.validate.password` plugin's JavaScript and CSS code was manually added to the jsFiddle since it's not hosted on a CDN.

**Demo #2:  http://jsfiddle.net/4JEUx/**

In order to have the password plugin ignore any `input` fields with `type="password"`, you must use `password: false` as the rule on those two `input` fields...

```
         rules: {
            "change_password[password]": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                password: false  // <-- to ignore password plugin
            },
            "change_password[new_password]": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                password: true  // <-- to use password plugin
            },
            "change_password[password_confirm]": {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#new_password",
                password: false  // <-- to ignore password plugin
            }
        },
```

You can then **remove** `class="password"` from the second `input` field as it's now superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. The form is being generated by symfony 1.4 and tbh tiredness meant I just hadn't noticed the wierd display:none and empty textfield things. Never seen it do this before and can't find a reason for it either.  I have just bypassed symfony forms to get this working.  The fiddle doesn't use the jquery.validate.password plugin, is this a mistake?
 I'm still working on getting your fix working but am making progress thanks to yo8ur pointer about targetting names not ids.

Comment: @Tofuwarrior, I misread the first part of your OP.  I've fixed your code and edited my answer accordingly.  Please don't forget to accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help sparky, still trying to track down why those wierd additional fields and display:none happening but your stuff works great. If you have time can you explain to me the issues around not putting 'form' in the submit handler, I'm pretty novice at javascript and jquery.

Comment: @Tofuwarrior, `submitHandler: function(form) {}` is the default `submitHandler` function as per the plugin documentation.  Leaving out `form` will only break it whenever you'd need to use `form` within the function.

Comment: thanks for clarification and help, got it all working thanks to your advice